# C# парсинг JSON

Tags: c#, json

Добрый день , столкнулся с проблемой при парсинге Json средствами C#.
Библиотека:Newtonsoft

При стандартном парсинге например:
JSON

```
  {"success":1,"return":2}
```

C#

```
    class info{
   public int success {get;set;}
   public int return{get;set;}
    }
    info result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<info>(jsonstring);
```

При таком раскладе все впорядке, вопросов нет.  А как быть со вложенными массивами, когда имя ветки не известно.
Например:

```
{
    "success":1,
    "return":{
        "ИМЯ И КОЛ ВО  НЕ ИЗВЕСТНО":{
            "per1":"auth",
            "timestamp_created":1418654530,
            "status":0
        },
        {
        "ИМЯ И КОЛ ВО  НЕ ИЗВЕСТНО":{
            "per1":"auth",
            "timestamp_created":1418654530,
            "status":0
        }
```

Как правильно составить класс?

Comment: Придется парсить ручками. `JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);` и далее `var children = obj.Children().ToArray();` на это строке ставим точку останова и просматриваем значение этой переменной - какие дети получились и с какими значениями, ну и далее используем остальные свойства и методы `JObject`, для вытаскивания нужных значений.

Comment: А почему неизвестно? Неужели документация не описывает формат?

Comment: Я отметил этот вопрос как дубликат более позднего потому что у текущего вопроса очень странное форматирование, которое не хочется ни переписывать, ни оставлять как есть. Если кто-то считает необходимым восстановление "исторической справедливости" или чего-то подобного, прошу начать с приведения вопроса в порядок.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В случае десериализации, именно данным способом, должно быть **обязательно известно имя**, так как на его **парсер JSON десериализует на основе класса**, который вы указываете при параметризации десериализатора. Однако количество знать не обязательно, вы можете указать свойство, количество которого не известно, как любую коллекцию. Например можете сделать вот так:
JSON

```
{
"success":1,
"return":{
    "answer":{
        "per1":"auth",
        "timestamp_created":1418654530,
        "status":0
    },
    {
    "answer":{
        "per1":"auth",
        "timestamp_created":1418654530,
        "status":0
    }
```

C#

```
class info{
   public int success {get;set;}
   public Answer[] return{get;set;}
}
class Answer
{
   public string per1 {get;set;}
   public uint timestamp_created {get;set}
   public int status {get;set}
}
```

Comment: В том то и проблема что answer(В моем случае там находится уникальный ID) и он меняется с каждой транзакцией.

Comment: Тогда можете воспользоваться JObject, как посоветовали вам в комментариях, официальная [документация](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm)

Answer (score 8):

Так-то всё просто: нужно использовать словарь (`Dictionary`) для узлов с неизвестным заранее названием.

Если бы вы привели валидный json, было бы намного легче дать точный ответ.

Допустим, имеется следующий json:

```
{
    "success":1,
    "return":{
        "name1":{
            "per1":"auth",
            "timestamp_created":1418654530,
            "status":0
        },
        "name2":{
            "per1":"auth",
            "timestamp_created":1418654530,
            "status":0
        }
    }
}
```

Набор классов для его десериализации:

```
public class Info
{
    [JsonProperty("success")]
    public int Success { get; set; } // можно заменить на bool

    [JsonProperty("return")]
    public Dictionary<string, Item> Return { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    [JsonProperty("per1")]
    public string Per1 { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("timestamp_created")]
    public int TimeStampCreated { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("status")]
    public int Status { get; set; }
}
```

Использование:

```
var info = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Info>(json);

Console.WriteLine(info.Success);

foreach (var ret in info.Return)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ret.Key + ":");

    var item = ret.Value;
    Console.WriteLine(item.Per1 + " " + item.TimeStampCreated + " " + item.Status);
}
```

Comment: `Dictionary` — хорошая идея!

Comment: Спасибо, помогли :)

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо использовать LINQ to JSON.
Так это работает:

```
JObject o = JObject.Parse(@"{
  'CPU': 'Intel',
   'Drives': [
     'DVD read/writer',
     '500 gigabyte hard drive'
   ]
 }");

string cpu = (string)o["CPU"];
// Intel

string firstDrive = (string)o["Drives"][0];
// DVD read/writer

IList<string> allDrives = o["Drives"].Select(t => (string)t).ToList();
// DVD read/writer
// 500 gigabyte hard drive
```

Для парсинга есть 3 основных объекта: `JObject`, `JArray`, `JValue`.

Официальная документация - https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm

В вашем случае для return (*JObject*) вам необходимо использовать свойство *JObject.ChildrenTokens*, которое получает все дочерние элементы.