# Парсинг JSON на C# и запись в коллекцию

Tags: c#, json, парсер, коллекции

Мне нужно обработать json и записать значения в коллекцию, делала по примеру из [вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/758617/c-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3-json), но у меня возникает ошибка. Библиотека: `Newtonsoft`.

**Пример JSON:**

```
{  
    "0": {   
        "id": 0,    
        "rus": "Россия", 
        "eng": "Russia",    
        "chn": "俄罗斯",    
        "visible": 1,   
        "retry": 1,    
        "rent": 1,    
        "multiService": 1  
    },  

    "1": {  
        "id": 1,    
        "rus": "Украина",    
        "eng": "Ukraine",    
        "chn": "乌克兰",    
        "visible": 1,    
        "retry": 1,    
        "rent": 1,    
        "multiService": 1 
    },  
}
```

**Классы на C#:**

```
class CountryJson
{
    [JsonProperty("Country")]
    public Dictionary<string, CountryItem> Country { get; set; }
}

class CountryItem
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("rus")]
    public string Rus { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("eng")]
    public string Eng { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("chn")]
    public string Chn { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("visible")]
    public int Visible { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("retry")]
    public int Retry { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("rent")]
    public int Rent { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("multiService")]
    public int MultiService { get; set; }

    public CountryItem(int id, string rus, string eng, string chn, int vis, int ret, int rent, int multi)
    {
        ID = id;
        Rus = rus;
        Eng = eng;
        Chn = chn;
        Visible = vis;
        Retry = ret;
        Rent = rent;
        MultiService = multi;
    }
}
```

**Попытка использования:**

```
    List<CountryItem> lst_country = new List<CountryItem>();

    var country = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CountryJson>(result);

    foreach (var c in country.Country)
    {
        var itemCountry = c.Value;

        lst_country.Add(new CountryItem(itemCountry.ID, itemCountry.Rus, itemCountry.Eng, itemCountry.Chn, 
            itemCountry.Visible, itemCountry.Retry, itemCountry.Rent, itemCountry.MultiService));
    }
```

Ошибка в том, что `country.Country` равняется `null`, значит я что-то делаю не так.

Comment: Вы пишете `JsonProperty("Country")`, но в приведенном json такого свойства нет

Comment: Вероятно вам нужно десериализовать не в `CountryJson`, а сразу в `Dictionary<string, CountryItem>`

Comment: @АндрейNOP: Да, так работает, я проверил. Напишете ответ?

Comment: > Вероятно вам нужно десериализовать не в CountryJson, а сразу в Dictionary<string, CountryItem> - да, похоже, тогда прокатит. Иногда помогает сервис https://json2csharp.com/

Comment: @АндрейNOP это помогло, спасибо большое!

Comment: @Афродита, напишите ответ, как получилось